# Ionic Native Camera is not calling getPicture() callback on Android Device

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, android-camera, ionic-native

I am working on Ionic Native Camera Plugin and have followed all instructions given here on the page in [official documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/camera/). Here is the code of I have written for it:

```
getPhoto(){

 console.log("In get Photo Method");
 const options: CameraOptions = {
 quality: 100,
 destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
 encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
 mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE
}


this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {  
console.log("Check Image"+imageData);}, 
(err) => {
console.log("Check Error Red"+err);
 });}
```

The console log I get on the chrome developer tools is displayed as below which shows no getPicture() being called:
[image]
But when I run it on browser just for the sake of testing, It shows console messages and warnings as below:
[image]

Note: No exception or app crash happens, The execution just simply get stuck at callback function  this.camera.getPicture

Comment: Can you post your code? Also are you inspecting your device or just using `ionic serve`?

Comment: @GabrielBarreto I have updated the code, I am running on device and inspecting it on chrome developer tools

Comment: Any native cordova plugins implemented in your code will throw a warning in the browser because the browser doesn't have the capabilities if you use ionic serve.

Comment: I know, I have shown results of running on both android device and browser. The first screenshot is from android device.

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain further what is your issue? you are not getting the photo or what?
Because the function is being called, console is logging the message correctly.

Comment: No this the method which contains the callback method. The results says "In get Photo Method" which is printed before callback method. When I debug it using breakpoints, The execution does not proceed after callback function.

Comment: ok wait i will try your code on my device and tell you what is wrong

Comment: One thing more when I run it  on browser, It gives me exceptions in console unlike device where no error or log statement is shown

Comment: look, i tried your code and working perfectly, i didn't add anything new, in the browser it will not work because it must be running on a simulator or a native device, try to check camera permission for the app on your phone

Comment: I have given permissions from settings in android. Also I tried to call method for permissions but same behavior. Which cordova-Android version are you using for Ionic?

Comment: check camera permission and update me so i can edit my answer

Comment: ok i'm using android 7, but we may try to remove plugin camera and re add it via cordova

Comment: Did it numerous times, No success though

Comment: What difference It would make? As I am following Ionic Official Documentation. The code sample is almost similar to code snippet available on their own website

Comment: i made some search via google and someone had the same issue you had, and the sample in the link worked for him, it might be an issue with your plugin version, can you write your plugin version?

Comment: The plugin number of  @ionic-native/camera: 4.15.0, and cordova-plugin-camera: ~4.0.3

Comment: mine is     "@ionic-native/camera": "^4.14.0",
    "cordova-plugin-camera": "^4.0.3",
edit the version then run the command npm install

Comment: Please mention the complete statement with example and do I just have to edit the version number in package.json file?

Comment: Solution you have mentioned does not work. Changed the version number but no effect.

Comment: I updated plugins and check the console. I found warning which states:                                                                                   Ionic Native: deviceready did not fire within 5000ms. This can happen when plugins are in an inconsistent state. Try removing plugins from plugins/ and reinstalling them. Do you know how to resolve  this warning?

Comment: This isn't an error that should stop your code from running, but maybe because device.ready is not fired, sorry for late reply, let me think of a solution for this

Comment: paste this code in app.component.ts
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.platform.ready()
  }

Comment: Should I paste in constructor?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181198/discussion-between-mohamed-wahshey-and-pheonix).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was due to conflict of plugins, Copied source code into new project and installed plugins which resulted in resolution of conflict and issue. There are suggested ways to reinstall plugins but non of them worked for ionic3.

Answer (score 0):

faced the same issue. i checked my cordova version and camera version, the camera version was like 2.4.20 but it was too old when i checked the documentation. So i updated the camera plugin and removed android platform and then added it again.